# XfdfReader in Itextsharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I am using  [itextsharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/)  latest version.

Could not understand why this code

```
XfdfReader x= new XfdfReader(filename);
```

showing this error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

It has no problem with **PdfReader** class

According to  [definition](http://opensourcejavaphp.net/csharp/itextsharp/XfdfReader.cs.html) XfdfReader class have 3 constructor in which one constructor take only one parameter filename and type of parameter is string. 
I give all the required parameter correctly but it show error.

Full code is given below...

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
         //it has no problem
         PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(ofd.FileName);
          //here is the error
          XfdfReader d=new XfdfReader(ofd.FileName);
        }
```

Comment: We're going to need more than the code you've given us. Either the XfdfReader constructor is choking on a `null` filename, or it is internally dying for some other reason, or something in some other code nearby.

Comment: Same issue for me. Did you got any solution